# Querying image into database

Tags: php, mysql, querying

I am trying to upload images to my database.

This is the form.

```
<form action='index.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <label>Change Profile Pic</label> <br>
    <input type='file' name='image'> <input type='submit' name=submitpicture
    value='Upload'>
</form>
```

This is the set of functions.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submitpicture']))

{
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','*****','*****');
    $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $imagename =  ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if($image_size== false)
{
    echo "This is not an image.";
}
else 
{

    if(!$link) //This links to my database.
    {
        echo "No link";
    }
        else
        {
        $picturedatabase = "INSERT INTO databaseimage ('name','image') VALUES ('name','$image')";


         if(mysqli_query($link,$picturedatabase));
         {
            echo "Entered into database";
         }
         }
}

}
```

When I upload an image, I get echoed back "Entered into Database" but when I check my database there are no rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't just insert the image into the database.
Instead, insert the image name and use that to load the image.

Comment: He can insert a base64 converted image into the database.

Comment: I am not inserting the plain image; I'm inserting the contents which are a series of symbols. Is that not what the file_get_contents() function does?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, set image like this:

```
$image= 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

Then, when you put it as an image src it will display the image.  This also will reduce requests.

Comment: what should I define the $type variable as?

Comment: Also, when I say "file_get_content($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])" alone, it should change the image into a bunch of gibberish symbols which can be uploaded into the database as a BLOB right?